# Trying to get text and image to fade when user scrolls down by using Intersection Observer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get text and images to fade as the user scrolls down. The code isn't working and I'm not sure if it's the CSS, HTML, or JS. I set the opacity in CSS to 0, but it doesn't fade to 1 when I scroll down. It just stays 0.

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Discover</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <img src="images/discover.jpg" alt="Not Loading" width="1470px" height="800px" class="background">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Not Loading" class="logo" width="400px" height="75px">
    <div class="title">DISCOVER</div>
    <div class="subText">Find Your Dream House From The Relaxation Of Your Couch</div>
    <a href="#text">
      <div class="learnMore">
        <h3>Learn More</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </header>
  <section class="bellow">
   
    <div class="UniqueStyle">
    <div class="UniqueStyleText">    
        <h2 class="hidden">Unique Style</h2>
        <p class="hidden"></p>
    </div>
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Not Loading" class="hidden">
   </div>

  </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 1000vh;
}
  
a {
    text-decoration: none; 
}
  
section {
    font-size: 2rem;
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 40px;
    color: blueviolet;
}
  
.container {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    perspective: 10px;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
  
header {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    z-index: -1;
}
  
.background {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
    filter: brightness(70%);
}
  
.logo {
    position: relative;
    right: 20spx;
    top: 10px;
}
  
.title {
    z-index: 1;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 120px;
    font-family: 'Nunito';
    position: relative;
    top: 15%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 400px;
    text-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
  
.subText {
    z-index: 1;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Nunito';
    position: relative;
    top: 13%;
    left: 10.5%;
    width: 700px;
    text-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
  
.learnMore {
    background-color: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 17%;
    left: 10%;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Nunito';
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
  
.learnMore:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}

.bellow {
    background-color: white;
}

.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}

.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JavaScript

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            entry.target.classList.add('show')
        } else {
            entry.target.classList.remove('show')
        }
    })
})

const hiddenElement = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden')
hiddenElement.forEach(el => observer.observe(el))
```

The program is supposed to add the class show to the divs with hidden. This would show the text and image.

Comment: Why are you adding/removing class show rather than removing/adding class hidden?

Answer (score 0):

I think u should add the `hidden` class from the element you want to fade-in by default.

```
<div class="UniqueStyle">
    <div class="UniqueStyleText hidden">
        <h2>Unique Style</h2>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Not Loading" class="hidden" />
</div>
```

Then add some transition in `hidden` class in css file:

```
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s ease; /* Add a transition for smooth fade-in effect */
}

.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

It works on my local, hope it will helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs for [intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), I think you should adjust the threshold inside of the options for the intersection observer. That way you can be informed every time a target's visibility passes backward or forward through each X% mark.

Add a value to threshold (other than 0) and check for that in the intersection observer callback.

[Intersection Observer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.25) {
            entry.target.classList.add('show')
        } else {
            entry.target.classList.remove('show')
        }
    })
}, {threshold: [0.25]})

const hiddenElement = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden')
hiddenElement.forEach(el => observer.observe(el))
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 1000vh;
}
  
a {
    text-decoration: none; 
}
  
section {
    font-size: 2rem;
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 40px;
    color: blueviolet;
}
  
.container {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    perspective: 10px;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
  
header {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    z-index: -1;
}
  
.background {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
    filter: brightness(70%);
}
  
.logo {
    position: relative;
    right: 20spx;
    top: 10px;
}
  
.title {
    z-index: 1;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 120px;
    font-family: 'Nunito';
    position: relative;
    top: 15%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 400px;
    text-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
  
.subText {
    z-index: 1;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Nunito';
    position: relative;
    top: 13%;
    left: 10.5%;
    width: 700px;
    text-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
  
.learnMore {
    background-color: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 17%;
    left: 10%;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Nunito';
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
  
.learnMore:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}

.bellow {
    background-color: white;
    height: 200vh;
}

.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div class="title">DISCOVER</div>
    <div class="subText">Find Your Dream House From The Relaxation Of Your Couch</div>
    <a href="#text">
      <div class="learnMore">
        <h3>Learn More</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </header>
  <section class="bellow">
   
    <div class="UniqueStyle">
    <div class="UniqueStyleText">    
        <h2 class="hidden">Unique Style</h2>
        <p class="hidden"></p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1689956533687-48a209951899?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzfHx8ZW58MHx8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="Not Loading" class="hidden" width="500" height="250">
   </div>

  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: None of the solutions worked.

Comment: @EthanSuwan, it's working in the code snippet

Comment: ? I tried copy and pasting. I'll try again. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know why your code snippet works. I think it's because you don't have a background image. Mine still doesn't work. I tried it with different project as well.